# Oracle XE/SQLPlus query display more items

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-xe

Is there a setting to allow Oracle XE/SQLPlus to display more items before beginning a new header?

For example:

```
First Name           SURNAME              Subject                    MARK
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
Rollo                Aslaug               Databases                    55
Rollo                Aslaug               Programming                  50
Rollo                Aslaug               Graphics                     65
Loki                 Laufeyson            Operating Systems            45
Loki                 Laufeyson            Programming                  40
Loki                 Laufeyson            Databases                    55
Ragna                Lothbrock            Databases                    80
Ragna                Lothbrock            Operating Systems            50
Ragna                Lothbrock            Programming                  65
Thor                 Odinson              Programming                  75
Thor                 Odinson              Graphics                     60

First Name           SURNAME              Subject                    MARK
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
Thor                 Odinson              Databases                    60
Floki                Rafna                Databases                    75
Floki                Rafna                Operating Systems            45
Floki                Rafna                Graphics                     70
```

Is there a setting to remove the 2nd header in the middle of the query results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL*Plus, you can change the `pagesize`

```
SQL> set pagesize 100
```

will repeat the headings every 100 rows rather than every 15.  You can set the `pagesize` value to (just about) whatever you'd like.  If you want to ensure that the headers are only written once, you can set it to a number much greater than the number of rows that the query will return.